# Как мне получить все элементы из localstorage, чтобы и 999 и 1 индекс отображался

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Я добавляю в localstorage элемент с индексом например 12. И если я проверяю length localstorage я получаю например 1. И тогда мне показывает что элемент не найден. Как мне получить все элементы из localstorage, чтобы и 999 и 1 индекс отображался. Постоянно натыкаюсь на эту проблему. Во всех прошлых проектах так и не решил.

```js
async function setLocalStorage() {
    localStorage.setItem(index, item.id);
    console.log(localStorage.length);
    let i = 0;
    for (i; i <= localStorage.length; i++) {
        console.log(localStorage[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: потому что local storage не массив, а объект, соответственно переберать его надо как объект

Comment: ну или же добавлять все элементы в отдельный массив, и записывать в localstorage уже сам массив

Comment: А можно пример кода?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
  var id = i;
  var item = i*10;
  localStorage.setItem(id, item);
}
for(var item in localStorage){
  console.log(item);
}
```

!НО, как я писал выше, localStorage - объект, со своими свойствами и методами. Поэтому, в консоль выводятся не только установленные нами свойства.
Я бы поступил так:

```
var arr = []
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
  var item = i*10;
  arr.push(item);
}
arr = JSON.stringify(arr);
localStorage.setItem('items', arr);
    
var getArr = localStorage.getItem('items');
getArr = JSON.parse(getArr);

for(var i=0; i<getArr.length; i++){
  console.log(getArr[i]);
}
```

Здесь необходимо перед записью преобразовать наш массив в JSON, иначе он запишется как строка